# if isset PHP not working?

Tags: php

Okay, Im trying to set a captcha up, However with this code in, it breaks.

```
if(isset($_POST["captcha"]))
    if($_SESSION["captcha"]==$_POST["captcha"])
```

When i do it with out it, the page works, but the captcha is letting incorrect submits through.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /hermes/waloraweb085/b2027/moo.lutarinet/jointest.php on line 71

```
<?php

$pagetitle = "Home";

$checkrank = 0;

include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/header.inc.php');

ECHO <<<END

<br><br>

<b><center><i><u>DO NOT</u> USE YOUR NEOPETS PASSWORD OR PIN NUMBER!!!</b></i></center>
<p>
?>


<?php session_start() ?> 
<center><P><FORM ACTION="join.pro.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" METHOD=POST>
   <table width="393" height="188" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
       <td width="150">Username</td>
       <td width="243"><input type=text name="name" value="" size=32 maxlength=15></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Password</td>
       <td><input type=password name="pass1" VALUE="" maxlength=15></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Confirm Password</td>
       <td><input type=password name="pass2" VALUE="" size=32 maxlength=15></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Security Code (4 Diget Number)</td>
       <td><input type=password name="security" VALUE="" size=32 maxlength=4></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Email Address</td>
       <td><INPUT TYPE=text NAME="email" VALUE="" SIZE=32 maxlength=100></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td height="41" colspan="2" valign="middle"><p><p><center>
         By registering an account here you agree to all

         of our <A HREF="$baseurl/tos.php">Terms and

       Conditions</A>. You can also view our <A HREF="$baseurl/privacy.php">Privacy

   Policy</A>. 
       </center></p></td>
     </tr>

<tr><td align="center">CAPTCHA:<br>
    (antispam code, 3 black symbols)<br>
    <table><tr><td><img src="captcha.php" alt="captcha image"></td><td><input type="text" name="captcha" size="3" maxlength="3"></td></tr></table>
</td></tr>
<td height="27" colspan="2" valign="middle">
         <center><input type=submit name=Submit value="Register"></center>
       </td>
</table>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["captcha"]))
if($_SESSION["captcha"]==$_POST["captcha"])
{
    //CAPTHCA is valid; proceed the message: save to database, send by e-mail ...
    echo 'CAPTHCA is valid; proceed the message';
}
else
{
    echo 'CAPTHCA is not valid; ignore submission';
}
?>


<?php



END;




include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/footer.inc.php');


?>
```

captcha.php

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); 
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); 
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 

function _generateRandom($length=6)
{
    $_rand_src = array(
        array(48,57) //digits
        , array(97,122) //lowercase chars
//      , array(65,90) //uppercase chars
    );
    srand ((double) microtime() * 1000000);
    $random_string = "";
    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
        $i1=rand(0,sizeof($_rand_src)-1);
        $random_string .= chr(rand($_rand_src[$i1][0],$_rand_src[$i1][1]));
    }
    return $random_string;
}

$im = @imagecreatefromjpeg("http://sketchedneo.com/images/sitedesigns/captcha.jpg"); 
$rand = _generateRandom(3);
$_SESSION['captcha'] = $rand;
ImageString($im, 5, 2, 2, $rand[0]." ".$rand[1]." ".$rand[2]." ", ImageColorAllocate ($im, 0, 0, 0));
$rand = _generateRandom(3);
ImageString($im, 5, 2, 2, " ".$rand[0]." ".$rand[1]." ".$rand[2], ImageColorAllocate ($im, 255, 0, 0));
Header ('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im,NULL,100);
ImageDestroy($im);
?>
```

Help please anyone?

Line 71:  if(isset($_POST["captcha"]))

Line 72: if($_SESSION["captcha"]==$_POST["captcha"])

Comment: Please include only relevant code in your examples.

Comment: ummmmmmmmmmmmm, whats on line 71 (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

You're missing `END;`:

```
ECHO <<<END

<br><br>

<b><center><i><u>DO NOT</u> USE YOUR NEOPETS PASSWORD OR PIN NUMBER!!!</b></i></center><p>

END; // You forgot to include this
```

By the way, `session_start()` should be the first thing called in your script as it needs to be done before any other output is initiated.

Also, try to get your braces in order with multi-line branches (makes it easier to scan):

```
if (isset($_POST["captcha"]))
{
    if ($_SESSION["captcha"] == $_POST["captcha"])
    {
        //CAPTHCA is valid; proceed the message: save to database, send by e-mail ...
        echo 'CAPTHCA is valid; proceed the message';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'CAPTHCA is not valid; ignore submission';
    }
}
```

Comment: Im still getting an error. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /hermes/waloraweb085/b2027/moo.lutarinet/jointest.php on line 71

Comment: With End I then get this Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /hermes/waloraweb085/b2027/moo.lutarinet/jointest.php:3) in /hermes/waloraweb085/b2027/moo.lutarinet/jointest.php on line 30 Which is: <?php session_start() ?>

Comment: Sessions_start at the top, Has fixed all errors :) Thank you. I am still learning PHP. I dont suppose you could help me again please? My captcha isnt working, I put a false code in and it still registers

Comment: Glad I could answer this question. Please checkmark this answer then ask a *new* question about the captcha not working. That way, different subjects are separated into different questions, making it easier for others to search for their particular issues in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST["captcha"]))
if($_SESSION["captcha"]==$_POST["captcha"])
{
    //CAPTHCA is valid; proceed the message: save to database, send by e-mail ...
echo 'CAPTHCA is valid; proceed the message';
}
else
{
    echo 'CAPTHCA is not valid; ignore submission';
}
```

You're missing a curly bracket on first if...

```
if(isset($_POST['captcha']))
{
    if($_SESSION['captcha'] == $_POST['captcha'])
    {
        //CAPTHCA is valid; proceed the message: save to database, send by e-mail ...
        echo 'CAPTHCA is valid; proceed the message';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'CAPTHCA is not valid; ignore submission';
    }
}
// Need another else for first if here or keep it closed if you don't have an else
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /hermes/waloraweb085/b2027/moo.lutarinet/jointest.php on line 72    which is: if(isset($_POST['captcha'])) {